# Django how to use post_save for upload image from another model

Tags: python, django

I am trying to copy image from my ProductImage models and upload it to my OrderItem models when any new order items will be create but got this error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'image'` but you can see my ProductImage model have image fields and also image exits for the current product which order is creating. here my two models:

```
#ProductImage Model
class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=dynamic_upload_path)
    thumb_image =  models.ImageField(upload_to=dynamic_upload_path,blank=True,null=True)

#OrderItem models

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True,null=True)
    product_image = models.ForeignKey(ProductImage, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True,null=True) 
    order_image_file = models.ImageField(blank=True,null=True,upload_to=orderImage_upload_path)
```

my signals:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=OrderItem)
def OrderItemSignals(sender, instance, created,**kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.order_image_file = instance.product_image.image
```

so basically when any order item will be create I want to fire my post save for copy image from my product image models and upload it to my order item models image fields.

Comment: Did you register the signal?

Comment: `instance.product_image` is None, the field allows null values so you need to handle this in your signal handler

Comment: @Iain Shelvington can u please show me how to handle the null value because  ProductImage model have image fields and also image exits for the current product which order is creating